# WriteableBitmap unavailable?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, c++-cli, version, writeablebitmap

I've discovered what may be the perfect answer to [a question on buffered drawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055920/how-to-write-to-a-bitmap-image-buffer-for-faster-gdi-displays), but for some reason my version of VS2008 doesn't seem to have a [`WriteableBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx)? I've tried including the relevent namespaces as per the documentation:

```
using namespace System::Windows::Media;
using namespace System::Windows::Media::Imaging;
```

But that just gives me errors:

```
d:\experiments\graphicscontrols\graphicscontrollib\GraphicsControlLibControl.h(9) : error C2039: 'Media' : is not a member of 'System::Windows'
d:\experiments\graphicscontrols\graphicscontrollib\GraphicsControlLibControl.h(10) : error C3083: 'Media': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type
d:\experiments\graphicscontrols\graphicscontrollib\GraphicsControlLibControl.h(10) : error C2039: 'Imaging' : is not a member of 'System::Windows'
d:\experiments\graphicscontrols\graphicscontrollib\GraphicsControlLibControl.h(52) : error C2065: 'WriteableBitmap' : undeclared identifier
```

Do I have an older version of .net installed or something? Is there any way to tell what version visual studio is using? I've updated VS to service pack 1 which made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must target .Net framework 3.0 or 3.5 to get this. Also you will need to add a ref to PresentationCore.dll.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing two references as it turns out: 'WindowsBase' and 'PresentationCore'