# How to color vertices of a triangle in c#

Tags: c#, graphics

I can draw triangle. Here is my code

```
    Graphics surface;
    surface = this.CreateGraphics();
    SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
    Point[] points = { new Point(100, 100), new Point(75, 50), new Point(50, 100) };
    surface.FillPolygon(brush, points);
```

How can I color 3 vertices of the triangle differently. Here i am using only blue color. But I want one vertex to be red, another one blue and another one green. How can I do that?

Comment: This can help you.. just follow the `OP's` same method of thinking and replace `Pen` with `Brush` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062622/fast-way-to-draw-lines-using-different-color-using-gdi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After drawing your polygon, draw circles representing your vertices on top.  If you were using only one color, I would recommend putting it into a `for` loop, but if you're changing brush colors, you might as well do it individually.

Add this to your code:

```
SolidBrush blueBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue); // same as brush above, but being consistent
SolidBrush redBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red); 
SolidBrush greenBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);

int vertexRadius = 1; // change this to make the vertices bigger

surface.fillEllipse(redBrush, new Rectangle(100 - vertexRadius, 100 - vertexRadius, vertexRadius * 2, vertexRadius * 2));
surface.fillEllipse(blueBrush, new Rectangle(75 - vertexRadius, 50 - vertexRadius, vertexRadius * 2, vertexRadius * 2));
surface.fillEllipse(greenBrush, new Rectangle(50 - vertexRadius, 100 - vertexRadius, vertexRadius * 2, vertexRadius * 2));
```

### Edit

I understand from your comments that you were looking to make gradients from one vertex to the next.  Here's the way to make a path gradient, based on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.pathgradientbrush.aspx) docs.  (If you didn't want to fill the inside with a gradient, you could just use [linear gradients](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.lineargradientbrush.aspx).)

```
PathGradientBrush gradientBrush = new PathGradientBrush(points);
Color[] colors = { Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Green };
gradientBrush.CenterColor = Color.Black;
gradientBrush.SurroundColors = colors;
```

Then just fill the polygon with the new brush:

```
surface.FillPolygon(gradientBrush, points);
```

Comment: you are just drawing some points at the vertices but it should radient the connecting line. Thanks anyway

Comment: @user1478137 I updated my answer.  I didn't understand from your question that you wanted gradients (you didn't make any mention of filling the triangle being what you wanted to change), but the Edit should get you what you want.  If you just want a gradient for the sides and not the fill, you'll need to look at the linear gradients link, make pens, and draw the lines instead of a polygon.